# ASN.1 real number encoding in base 2 with pyasn1

Tags: python, encoding, asn.1

I started to learn ASN.1 and used pyasn1 for my experiments.
By default pyasn1 use base 10 to encode real numbers.
It is also support base 2 and I need to use base 2 in my program.
But it looks something wrong with encoding.
I found strange behaviour when encode numbers 0.5 and 1.0 in base 2.
The test code is:

```
from pyasn1.type import univ
from pyasn1.codec.ber import encoder, decoder
import binascii

for i in xrange(4):
    r=univ.Real((1,2,-i))
    m=encoder.encode(r)
    print r,"->",decoder.decode(m)[0],"data:",binascii.b2a_hex(m)
```

The output is:

```
1.0 -> 2.0 data: 0903830101
0.5 -> 2.0 data: 0903830101
0.25 -> 0.25 data: 090380fe01
0.125 -> 0.125 data: 090380fd01
```

Both numbers 0.5 and 1.0 encoded as the same sequence and decoded as 2.0 number.
The same behaviour is in both BER and DER encoders.

Could you please help me to find out what is wrong?

Comment: Looks like this bug fixed in latest version of pyasn1

Comment: The fix is actually in development version only at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour corresponds to the bug already fixed in the development version of pyasn1.
For current version the fix is to do next change:
in the file pyasn1/codec/ber/encoder.py find lines encoding exponent

```
        eo = null
        while e not in (0, -1):
            eo = int2oct(e&0xff) + eo
            e >>= 8
        if e == 0 and eo and oct2int(eo[0]) & 0x80:
            eo = int2oct(0) + eo
        n = len(eo)
        if n > 0xff:
            raise error.PyAsn1Error('Real exponent overflow')
        if n == 1:
            pass
        elif n == 2:
            fo |= 1
        elif n == 3:
            fo |= 2
        else:
            fo |= 3
            eo = int2oct(n//0xff+1) + eo
```

and replace them with these lines

```
        eo = null
        while True:
            _e = e&0xff
            eo = int2oct(_e) + eo
            e >>= 8
            if e==0: # positive number ends up with 0
                if not _e&0x80: # sequence should start with positive byte
                    break
            elif e==-1: # negative number ends up with -1
                if _e&0x80: # sequence should start with negative byte
                    break
        n = len(eo)-1
        if n > 0xff:
            raise error.PyAsn1Error('Real exponent overflow')
        if n < 3:
            fo |= n
        else:
            fo |= 3
            eo = int2oct(n) + eo
```